# Android Map View Issue

Tags: android, android-maps

I am having an app which tracks the Geopoints of the user. I simply fetch these points and use them to draw the path on Map View.

```
   My issue is, when I see the path tracked by user, the path seems to be correctly plotted but, when I have a first look over the map,it does not show me an entire zoomed out view of the map where I can see all the track path. Instead the map begins with from where I started tracking and then I need to scroll all my way to see the further tracks.
```

Please Help. :)
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MapController.zoomToSpan(...)](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html#zoomToSpan%28int,%20int%29), you can get the span from your ItemizedOverlay methods [getLatSpan(int)](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#getLatSpanE6%28%29) and [getLonSpan(int)](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#getLonSpanE6%28%29). zoomToSpan(...) is a best effort method and does not guarantee that all points will be visible.